# Office window doesn't respond to any actions

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a problem with MS Office 2016 Standard. It installs and runs perfectly, but when I try to interact with the app's window (Word, Excel and other), it doesn't respond to any actions (clicking, text typing, etc.). If I resize the window, then it shows me the result of my actions (typed text, menu tab that I clicked). Therefore, I have to resize the window to see the result of my actions. Nevertheless, only the first menu tab "File" works fine, I can open, save, close files, open properties window. Thanks in advance.

===============================

Solution.
The solution of this problem is to update GPU driver to the latest version. The laptop has an Intel Celeron B800 with integrated GPU.

Thanks for your tips, guys!=)

Comment: Try two things:  (1) Uninstall Office, restart, install it again and patch fully.  Restart and test.   (2) Make a new, test Windows User Profile (account), log into the new Windows Account and test Office in the new Windows Account

Comment: Also, update your graphics drivers.

Comment: Try to use Office tool uninstall Office completely and re-install it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8